# how to convert a string representation of a list to a list with the tidyverse

Tags: r

```
s <- "['Russia', 'Ukraine', 'The West', 'EU', 'Germany', 'France']"
```

What is a good way to parse a string representing a list of values into a vector in R? [I have a data frame where a column is a list of such strings.]

Comment: Is this string a syntactically valid representation of a list in some language?  Python, for instance?

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised I can't find a similar post already here, but I've had to do this to translate snippets from Javascript or Python. With base R, remove the brackets and quotation marks, split, and flatten the list it returns.

```r
s <- "['Russia', 'Ukraine', 'The West', 'EU', 'Germany', 'France']"
unlist(strsplit(gsub("[\\[\\]']", "", s, perl = TRUE), ", "))
#> [1] "Russia"   "Ukraine"  "The West" "EU"       "Germany"  "France"
```

Alternatively, include `\\s` inside the brackets of the regex to remove spaces, then split by just commas.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `reticulate` as the `list` showed is a python `list`

```
library(reticulate)
py_run_string(paste0('s =', s))
py$s
[1] "Russia"   "Ukraine"  "The West" "EU"       "Germany"  "France"
```

---

Or we may use `chartr` to replace the `[]` with `()` and use `eval/parse` to read in `base R`

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("c", chartr('[]', '()', s))))
[1] "Russia"   "Ukraine"  "The West" "EU"       "Germany"  "France"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than eval parse as an input method, consider usin ‘scan’

```
In.vec <- as.list( scan( text = gsub( “[[|\]]”, ‘’, s ) )
```

Warning. Not tested. Sent from iPhone so the quotes might be smart-quote and need to be replaced by double quotes. And doing the pattern by memory. Tricky to use character classes on square brackets.